# GPIO PCM on RPi 3 B model

Tags: python, audio, c

I have a decoder from a PCM system. I want to stream digital sound by the PCM pins of my RPi using the CLK, FS, and digital output to complete my PCM system.

I have been looking for information, but I just found some [ALSA C](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html) code which I am not familiar with.

After all, I have a few questions:

1. How can I able this pines with python.
2. I tried to set the PCM CLK pin with python but I only achieved 2 KHz. I'd like to achieve at least 4 KHz.
3. If python can't do this. When running a C program, does it write directly on the ICE RPi chip? Can I recover the factory settings if something goes wrong?